# Notify a commentator of new information on the original question

Tags: support, editing, notifications

How can I notify a user that placed a comment on my original question asking for extra information?

This is because I once gave the extra information as a comment but it was placed on the original question and i was told that "new information goes in your question, not comments!"

But if I do this the commentator will not receive a notification, there is nothing in this [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) that suggests that the commentator will be notified over an edit to the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply leave a comment like

> @user I've updated my post with more details

Eventually these will be removed or hidden by moderators or the system as comments are treated a lot like second class citizens, in that they don't matter as much as the Question and Answers.

Comment: What if I leave that comment, wait around 5 min, and then eliminate it myself? Will it still notify the commentator? In order to save some work to the moderators.

Comment: @xynkrn The previous user's comment will still need to be removed. Some users will remove their comments after they see the post is updated, other won't. It's really not much of a worry since, as I mentioned before, comments kind of "fold away" when they become to noisy.